# Can a stove be beneath a window

Tags: safety, kitchens, design, layout

I'm upgrading my kitchen and after endless deliberating, feel that the kitchen is best laid out having the stove directly beneath a window (the window is about 8" above the stove).

I was wondering whether there are any huge reasons why i should avoid doing this.

Answer (score 13):

A few concerns:

- The range hood will need to be placed above the window, possibly blocking some of your view, unless you install a downdraft vent frequently seen in cooking islands.
- If you have a messy cook in the house, cleaning the grease off of the window panes and crevices will be all the more difficult on a window.  And curtains or blinds are even worse.
- In the winter, boiling water close to the window will result in a lot of condensation.  If that runs down the window and freezes, you could be looking at some damage.

None of this says you can't do it.  I doubt that the thermal changes will break the glass, but I couldn't say for sure.  But all other things being equal (which you say they aren't) I would choose somewhere other than the window myself.

Answer (score 7):

I would love to look out over my stove into the yard, but I highly recommend you don't configure your kitchen this way.

1. The thermal gradient may weaken the seal on double pane glass. The bottom will be hot and the top will be ambient. Intense heat may prematurely age the window sealing material.
2. You can never put curtains or plastic blinds / curtains above it.
3. Cooking always splatters, even the best cooks have bits of starch shoot out of the boiling water or oil shoot up when sauteing something. You'll be constantly cleaning the windows event if you are an immaculate cook.
4. Debris (pollen / water) coming into the window adds a risk to food prep and sanitation.
5. There is a risk that you would reach over the stove to manipulate the window while the stove is on, such as when it rains and you don't want water going into your frying fish. :)

It's a lovely idea, but I would put the sink there instead. Hope this helps!

Sam

Answer (score 2):

if you don't have open fire stove and curtains on the window above it, there probabaly isn't any reason for concern.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a gas stove it should not be placed close to a window or exterior door:

- A draft could blow out the flame or interfere with the cooking; and
- Direct sunlight will make the flame very difficult to see.